# Query MAX group by

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to Query in only the most recent entries of each part number. I can usually figure this stuff out but cannot figure out why it only returns the (date) and not the (part number) and (most recent Quantity).

```
=QUERY(A2:C, "Select MAX(A) group by (B)")
```

See example file: [query Max group by](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1li1mkvqGirORTikEIoEGP4aa168uSDyMxVypeB09T08/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 4):

Try using this:

```
=QUERY(A2:C, "Select A, B, C ORDER BY A DESC LIMIT 1")
```